# How to find all the parameters in weight vector in Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm?

Tags: abaqus, statistics

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I already had a data for corroded thickness distribution (in matrix form) for corroded surface model in Abaqus with mesh size 5 cm
I want to create thickness distribution with bigger mesh size (e.g 50 cm) but I dont want to use average thickness to obtain the smaller matrix size,
I want to use effective thickness by utilizing the equations in the picture.
But till today I still have no idea how to use those equations.
Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Similar to this question and it has a detailed answer : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19239/what-does-a-the-input-of-the-activation-function-mean